# Highcharts yAxis self-adaption issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I write a demo for my project,it works all right except Y-Axis does not adapt my data.It shows 100 max all the time,I searched on Internet that It should be self-adapted,but it doesn't.Anyone can help me would be appreciated,here is my code:

`$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
            chart : {
                                type : 'column'
                            },
                            title : {
                                text : 'IP subnet statics'
                            },
                            xAxis : {
                                categories : [ 'subnnet1', 'subnet2', 'subnet3' ]
                                //categories : result.subnets
                            },
                            yAxis : {
                                min : 0,
                                title : {
                                    text : 'total IP'
                                }

                            },
                            tooltip : {
                                pointFormat : '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
                                shared : true
                            },
                            plotOptions : {
                                column : {
                                    stacking : 'percent'
                                }
                            },
                            series : [ {
                                name : 'free',
                                data : [22,33,55]
                            }, {
                                name : 'occupy',
                                data : [11,22,33]
                            } ]
    });
});`

[image]

Comment: So according to you what result are you expecting and what is wrong that is not working perfectly ? It would be good if you create a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked for 'percent' stacking, which makes each column add up to 100. I think you may want 'normal' stacking

Change:

```
                       plotOptions : {
                            column : {
                                stacking : 'percent'
                            }
                        },
```

to

```
                       plotOptions : {
                            column : {
                                stacking : 'normal'
                            }
                        },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.stacking

Comment: I work it out by myself as the same way in your answer.Thanks anyway!